# Summation with Nulls and Custom Buckets

Tags: sql, postgresql

How do I add three values (value in C1, C2, C3) if one or more of the fields is null? I'd like it to add nulls as zero and put the total in a new field four. Right now my query simply returns null if at least one of the values is null.

For example this is what is happening (row two, field four comes up null because field two is null)

```
1 |   3  |   5  |   9
2  | NULL |   3   |  NULL
8  |   1  |    1  |   10
```

For example this is what I want to happen in my return set

```
1 |   3  |   5  |   9
2  | NULL |   3   |  5
8  |   1  |    1  |   10
```

Ideally, I'd like to also then add a fifth column to group these values into buckets of say "1-3", "4-6", "7-10" based on the value in field four. Admittedly, I have no idea how to do this part - any help or tips would be helpful.

```
1 |   3  |   5  |   9  | 7-10
2  | NULL |   3   |  5  | 4-6
8  |   1  |    1  |   10  | 7-10
```

It has been a few years since I worked in PostgreSQL so I'm guessing I'm just screwing something up simple. Any help on my query below would be most appreciated.

`SELECT "FIELD ONE", "FIELD TWO", "FIELD THREE", "FIELD ONE + FIELD TWO + FIELD THREE" AS "TOTAL FIELD" FROM "Table1";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way uses `coalesce()`:

```
select t.*,
       (coalesce(field1, 0) + coalesce(field2, 0) + coalesce(field3, 0)
       ) as total
from t;
```

Then you can use a `case` expression.  But, I like using a lateral join as well:

```
select t.*,
       (case when total <= 3 then '1-3'
             when total <= 6 then '4-6'
             else '7-10'
        end) as range
from t left join lateral
     (select sum(field) as total
      from (values (field1), (field2), (field3)) v(field)
     ) s
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm still having trouble with the grouping but I'm going to reformat my question and see if providing more information helps. I totally forgot about coalesce.